# Create a Gradle task that runs another task twice with different parameters

Tags: gradle, android-gradle-plugin

My current use case requires me to publish a separate set of debug and release artifacts. The steps are:

1. build AARs
2. build debug artifacts
3. build release artifacts

On the command line, I issue these commands.

```
./gradlew assemble
./gradlew buildArtifact -PPUBLISH_CONFIG=debug
./gradlew buildArtifact -PPUBLISH_CONFIG=release
```

Unfortunately, to work around limitations in the `buildArtifact` maven plugin, I have to execute it twice with different parameters.

Is there a way a create a **single** gradle task that runs `buildArtifact` twice with the different params? Having to run the `buildArtifact` command twice as separate commands is limiting. Ideally, my flow would become something like:

```
./gradlew assemble
./gradlew buildArtifacts
```

Comment: I am not familiar with a task `buildArtifacts` and I can't find anything about this. Where does it come from? Is this a custom task?

Comment: it's actually a wrapper around `publish` from `maven-publishing` https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/publishing_maven.html

The reason it's weird and I need to run it twice is to workaround that it doesn't support variant aware publishing https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/72181827

Comment: A solution could be to use subprojects for every variant, each with its own buildArtifacts configuration and task. If this is not applicable, you might want to introduce two tasks with type of your wrapper task. You should wire them with the existing publishing workflow.